# error BC30560: 'XlDirection' is ambiguous in the namespace 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Tags: vba, excel, vsto

I have a strange problem with Excel automation in VSTO. The below code works well with English but not with German language. The error is coming from first line of the code below. I get the following error when I watch the execution. Can someone tell me what's going wrong with the language setting.

> ```
> error BC30560: 'XlDirection' is ambiguous in the namespace 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel'.
>
> {System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->  
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Old format or invalid type library. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80028018  
> (TYPE_E_INVDATAREAD))  
>    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---  
>    at System.RuntimeType.InvokeDispMethod(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Object target, Object[] args, Boolean[]
> byrefModifiers, Int32 culture, String[] namedParameters)
>    at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs,
> ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
>    at System.Dynamic.IDispatchComObject.GetMembers(IEnumerable`1 names)}
> ```

```
wrkSheet.Range(wrkSheet.Range(IDTable), _
    wrkSheet.Range(IDTable).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlToRight) _
    .End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown)).Select()

Dim rngData As Excel.Range = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection
With rngData
    StartRng = .Find(FormulaString, LookIn:=Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlFormulas)
    If Not StartRng Is Nothing Then
        EndRng = StartRng
        StartAddress = StartRng.Address
        Do
            EndAddress = EndRng.Address
            EndRng = .FindNext(EndRng)
        Loop While Not EndRng Is Nothing And EndRng.Address <> StartAddress
    End If
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the `End` property incorrectly.  Try removing the references to `Excel.XlDirection`.

For example, change:

```
End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown)
```

...to:

```
End(xlDown)
```

---

**See the documentation for the property:**

- MSDN : [**`Range.End` Property** (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-end-property-excel)

---

If Excel's constants are not recognized, you can either declare them yourself or else substitute the actual values in your code:

## XlDirection Enumeration (Excel)

[image: img]

Comment: That does not work for VSTO. Here is the error. error BC30451: 'xlDown' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: The value of the `xlDown` constant is `-4121` so you can substitute that.

Comment: I am not sure why this code works under English language settings but not under German settings. I do have a similar line in other function that works fine but only this instance is resulting in the error. It looks like some reference error which is causing the problem when I change the language of Microsft office.

Comment: I now understand the issue. The issue was mainly due to the fact that the formula string is in English, when I use the .Find command, the result was always Null. I need to fix this with FormulaLocal or something else. I will post the solution when ready.